# onclick cannot find click handler in dynamically created table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I have a below html table which I am populating dynamically:

```
<table id="dataHere">
 <thead>
  <tr><td>Num</td></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a script tag in the same file where I am populating dynamically the rows of this table:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function sayHello(num){ console.log("Hello:"+num);}
        var dataRow = ``;
        for(let i=0;i<5;++i)
            dataRow+=`<tr><td onclick="sayHello(${i})">Hello, ${i}</td></tr>`; 
        $("#dataHere tbody").html(dataRow);
        })
        </script>
```

When I click on any of the cell here, I get error on console that `sayHello` is not defined.

What could be the possible reason behind it?

I have also tried doing like, `onclick=${sayHello(i)}`, but in that case it immediately invokes this function as soon as table is rendered.

Why it cannot find `sayHello` function? Please help me to find the reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the sayHello function out side the $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: It worked! But Why it didn't work earlier?

Comment: Scope, When you had it in the (document).ready(function(){ it only was only accessible from with in that function. Out side the function it is globally accessible. For more details https://javascript.info/closure